# What is the derivative of $\min(f(x),\text{constant})$, wrt $x$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$f(x)$ is a continuous function of $x$ which may be less than, equal to or greater than a fixed constant, say, $a$. If I have to differentiate "$\min(f(x),a)$", how do I do it? Its a part of a much bigger problem, so I cant go about breaking it in three separate cases.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: everywhere the derivative of $g$ defined by $g(x) = min(f(x), A)$ exists is either $f'(x)$ or $0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big hint:
$$
\min \{f(x),a\} = \frac{f(x)+a}{2}-\frac{|f(x)-a|}{2}.
$$
Now you have a clean function to differentiate.